# WPF ListBox displays duplicate items. How to get around?

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, listbox, backgroundworker, observablecollection

I have a ListBox with a nested ListBox inside. Both have ObservableCollections as their ItemsSource set with the inner ListBox's collection being a member of the outer one's Objects...

The collections are filled by a BackgroundWorker which gathers data from a webservice. I had to change from ObservableCollection to an AsyncObservableCollection in order to be able to add items from within the worker's code. AsyncObservableCollection code is from here: [Have worker thread update ObservableCollection that is bound to a ListCollectionView](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/01/16/have-worker-thread-update-observablecollection-that-is-bound-to-a.aspx)

My problem is that the inner ListBox keeps to display duplicate items. It seems as if it always duplicates the first item if it decides to duplicate. I have no clue why this happens. With an event listener attached to the CollectionChanged event of the collection I found out that the event is being fired fine once per item.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks,
Stephan

Comment: You are going to have to give us some more detail here. Try reducing your code down to the smallest possible example that still exhibits this issue, then update your question to include all the code.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to reproduce the behaviour in a small example. Other than that I am not allowed to blast out my code to the net, so I guess I have to deal with the problem on my own. Thanks to everyone who would have helped anyway ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out that the AsyncObservableCollection caused the problems. Obviously it messed up with some events or whatever.
I ended up in adding items to the collection in the worker's ProgressChanged method.

Comment: could you explain some more? I have that exact same problem. Seems like a timing issue btw (if I wait 100ms when adding content to the AsyncObservableCollection there are no ghost-items. Weird - anyways, I don't get your solution, could you explain? Did you ditch the AsyncObservableCollection?

Answer (score 1):

If you bind your ItemsSource to an AsyncObservableCollection, you must using a VistualizingStackPanel to correct this problem :

```
<ListBox
 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource YourItemTemplate}"
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourAsyncObservableCollection}" 
 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
 Style="{DynamicResource YourListBoxStyle}">
 <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my custom `INotifyCollectionChanged` collection and a `TreeView` the other day. It took my a few hours of debugging to figure out what the main problem was. As I didn't find any information on what causes this kind of behavior on the web, I decided to share my results here.

The root cause of this behavior is that apparently the underlying `CollectionView` that is responsible for handling `CollectionChanged` events raised by the collection in `ItemsControl` controls, does not solely depend on the information provided by the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` instances to update the UI. It also takes the contents of the collection at the time of receiving the notification into account.

Consider performing the following actions to the collection:

1. Clear the collection (without raising `CollectionChanged`)
2. Add item A to the collection (without raising `CollectionChanged`)
3. Raise `CollectionChanged` event for Clear action performed in step 1 (`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.Action = NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset`)
4. Raise `CollectionChanged` event for Add action performed in step 2 (`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.Action = NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add`)

Doing so will make item A appear twice in the UI. The reason is that when the `CollectionView` receives the first `CollectionChanged` notification (step 3), it doesn't care if the `Action` of the event args is `Reset`, it looks at the collection and sees there is one item in the collection. So it adds the item to the control. Then when it receives the second notification (step 4), it thinks a new item has been added to the collection and adds the item again to the control!

I'm not sure if this behavior is expected or not, but it's there.